# multidimensional array multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 multidimensional arrays. I want to multiply those arrays.

My both arrays have shape :

```
shape : (3, 100)
```

I want to convert matlab code :

```
sum(q1.*q2)
```

to

```
np.dot(q1, q2)
```

gives me output :

```
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Comment: `np.dot` is matrix multiply, numpy uses `*` for element wise multiply.

Comment: @BiRico -- That was my first thought as well (but I wasn't confident enough in my matlab to know for sure what the `.*` operator was doing).  Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My installation of Octave, when asked to do

```
sum(a .* b)
```

with `a` and `b` having shape `(3, 100)`, returns an array of shape `(1, 100)`. The exact equivalent in numpy would be:

```
np.sum(a * b, axis=0)
```

which returns an array of shape `(100,)`, or if you want to keep the dimensions of size 1:

```
np.sum(a * b, axis=0, keepdims=True)
```

You can get the same result, possibly faster, using `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->j', a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Matrix element wise product `*` instead of `dot` product

Here is a sample run with a reduced dimension

**Implementation**

```
A = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,4))
B = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,4))
result = A * B
```

**Demo**

```
>>> A
array([[4, 1, 3, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> B
array([[1, 3, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 4, 3]])
>>> A * B
array([[4, 3, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 2, 4],
       [0, 0, 4, 3]])
```